# how to change position of ol css?

Tags: css, list

I want the position of ol list item in the middle of content.

My code:

```
#block-views-credit-library-block-1 .item-lists ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin: 0 15px 25px;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
#block-views-credit-library-block-1 .item-lists ol li {
  background: url("../images/number.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  color: #F9F9F9;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 0 0 13px;
}
```

See the issue image: http://manjitsingh.org/sites/default/files/test.png
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please share your html as well it will help us to find issue in less time. otherwise you can make it on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: <div class="item-lists">
  <ol>
     <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
         <div class="views-field views-field-title">
           <span class="field-content">
              <a href="/adw_dev/ADW/content/abico-antehabeo-nunc-pagus-te-tum">Abico Antehabeo Nunc Pagu</a>
           </span>
         </div>
         <div class="views-field views-field-body">
             <div class="field-content">Commodo erat eum. Eu mauris vulpes. Commodo letalis molior neque os singularis sino vel volutpat. At utrum.</div>
         </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Use this css on your `ol li` block:

```
background-position: 0 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try using:

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -div height / 2;
position: absolute;
```